# Accessing pointer in shared memory

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm editing the whole question again, since the previous post was not a full minimal reproducible example. This is the complete code. Thanks if anyone can help.

The `struct destinations *destinations` is dynamically allocated within the functions `*getDestinations` and `createDestination`; when I write it on the `airplane_array` (which is lately written on the shared memory `shmp`), I can read its elements (`city` and `airport`) without any problem.

As soon as the new forked program, initialized with execve, try to access to the `airplane_array` elements (those who are dinamically allocated), it looks the program stop to work (the latest printf gets not called).
Note: as you can see, the new program is detaching from the shared memory, in order to re-attach to the previous initialized region (which address was stored in `shmataddress`).
Note: there is no problem if I access the `int company`, even if I don't "re-attach" the memory.

I already checked that the shared memory address, like the addresses of the elements, are correct, as you can see in the output log.
Can you help me in understanding how to access `city` and `airport` variables, after execve gets called, OR how should I re-design the `struct destinations *destinations` variable?

CLASS.C:

```
#define SHM_KEY 0x105

#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

struct destinations *getDestinations();
struct destinations createDestination();

struct destinations{
   int city;
   int airport;
};

struct airplane {
   int company;
   struct destinations *destinations;
};

struct shmseg {      
   void *shmatAddress;
   struct airplane airplane_array[];
};

int num_airplanes = 10;
int shmid;
pid_t childPid;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   struct shmseg *shmp;
   int i, j, k = 0;
   
   size_t shmp_size = sizeof(struct shmseg) + (num_airplanes * sizeof(struct airplane));
   shmp = (struct shmseg *) malloc(shmp_size);
   
   if (shmp == NULL) {}
   
   if((shmid = shmget(SHM_KEY, sizeof(struct shmseg) + (num_airplanes * sizeof(struct airplane)), IPC_CREAT | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)) == -1){
   }
   
   if ((shmp = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (void*) -1){
   }
   
   shmp->shmatAddress = (void *)shmp;
   
   
   for(i=0; i<1; i++){
   switch(childPid = fork()){
      case -1:{}
      case 0:{
         char *argv[] = {NULL};
         char *envp[] = {NULL};
         
         struct destinations *destinations_array = NULL;
         destinations_array = getDestinations();
         
         shmp->airplane_array[i].destinations = malloc(num_airplanes * sizeof(struct destinations));
               
         for( j=0;j<4;j++){
            memcpy(&shmp->airplane_array[i].destinations[j], &destinations_array[j], sizeof(struct destinations));
         }
         
         for ( k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            printf("SHMP: %d - %d\n", 
            shmp->airplane_array[i].destinations[k].city, shmp->airplane_array[i].destinations[k].airport);
         }
         
         printf("Address of destinations before execve: %p\n", (void *)shmp->airplane_array[0].destinations);
         printf("Address of destinations[0] before execve: %p\n", (void *)&shmp->airplane_array[0].destinations[0]);
         printf("Address of destinations[0].city before execve: %p\n", (void *)&shmp->airplane_array[0].destinations[0].city);
         printf("Address of destinations[0].airport before execve: %p\n", (void *)&shmp->airplane_array[0].destinations[0].airport);
         
         printf("shmp address before execve: %p\n", (void *)shmp);
         
         execve("./newprogram", argv, envp);
         
      }
      default:
   }
   }
   return 0;
}

struct destinations *getDestinations(){
   struct destinations *destinationsRet = NULL;
   int countDestinations = 0;
   int i = 0;
   for(i=0; i<4; i++){
      struct destinations my_destination = createDestination();
      destinationsRet = (struct destinations *) realloc(destinationsRet, (countDestinations + 1) * sizeof(struct destinations));
      destinationsRet[i] = my_destination;
      countDestinations++;
   }
   return destinationsRet;
}

struct destinations createDestination(){
   struct destinations my_destination;
   my_destination.city = 100;
   my_destination.airport = 200;
   return my_destination;
}
```

NEWPROGRAM.C:

```
#define SHM_KEY 0x105

#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

struct shmseg *shmp;

struct destinations{
   int city;
   int airport;
};

struct airplane {
   int company;
   struct destinations *destinations;
};

struct shmseg {      
   void *shmatAddress;
   struct airplane airplane_array[];
};

int shmid;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

   int num_airplanes = 10;
   int k = 0;

   void *address;

   if ((shmid = shmget(SHM_KEY, sizeof(struct shmseg) + (num_airplanes * sizeof(struct destinations)), 0)) == -1) {
   }

   if ((shmp = (struct shmseg *)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (void *)-1) {
   }
   
   address = shmp->shmatAddress;
   
   printf("shmp address after execve (before re-attaching): %p\n", (void *)shmp);
   
   if (shmdt(shmp) == -1) {
   }
   
   if ((shmp = (struct shmseg *)shmat(shmid, address, SHM_RND || SHM_REMAP)) == (void *)-1) {
   }
   
   printf("shmp address after execve (after re-attaching): %p\n", (void *)shmp);
   
   printf("Address of destinations after execve: %p\n", (void *)shmp->airplane_array[0].destinations);
   printf("Address of destinations[0] after execve: %p\n", (void *)&shmp->airplane_array[0].destinations[0]);
   printf("Address of destinations[0].city after execve: %p\n", (void *)&shmp->airplane_array[0].destinations[0].city);
   printf("Address of destinations[0].airport after execve: %p\n", (void *)&shmp->airplane_array[0].destinations[0].airport);

   for ( k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
      printf("SHMP from new program: %d - %d\n", 
      shmp->airplane_array[0].destinations[k].city, shmp->airplane_array[0].destinations[k].airport);
   }

   printf("program will die before this.\n");
   
   return 0;

}
```

OUTPUT LOG:

```
SHMP: 100 - 200
SHMP: 100 - 200
SHMP: 100 - 200
SHMP: 100 - 200
Address of destinations before execve: 0x1045380
Address of destinations[0] before execve: 0x1045380
Address of destinations[0].city before execve: 0x1045380
Address of destinations[0].airport before execve: 0x1045384
shmp address before execve: 0x7f3ceeb60000
shmp address after execve (before re-attaching): 0x7ff2ff80d000
shmp address after execve (after re-attaching): 0x7f3ceeb60000
Address of destinations after execve: 0x1045380
Address of destinations[0] after execve: 0x1045380
Address of destinations[0].city after execve: 0x1045380
Address of destinations[0].airport after execve: 0x1045384
```

Comment: I'm confused why you're allocating one size to `sharedMemory->myArray[j].product_1` but then `memcpy` ing a different amount.  You've provided no informatino on how `shmid` is provided.  I'm not sure how you expect anyone to debug this.

Comment: I've not used shared memory on Linux - only Windows - so my comments may be slightly off base here, but 1) it looks odd that you first allocate a `sharedMemory` buffer with `malloc()` and then immediately overwrite that pointer with what `shmat` returns. 2) what `malloc()` returns is _not_ in shared memory, so with the `sharedMemory->myArray[j].product_1` assignment, the forked process can see the pointer value, since that is put into shared memory, but not access what it points to since that memory is private to the calling process.

Answer (score 2):

On most modern operating systems each program has its own virtual address space. When you connect a program to a shared memory region it is added to that programs address space. HOWEVER the place where it is added in each program may not be the same. In practical terms this means that when designing programs that use shared memory you generally should not write any pointers into the shared memory region.

To double check if this is what is happening in your case you could try printing out the value of `sharedMemoryAddress` in each of your programs. It should (or at least might) be different. If it is different, that means that an address written to the shm will only work for the program that writes it.

Disclaimer: I didn't go through your code in detail here, there may also be other issues at hand.

Comment: Thanks you, I posted a full version of the code so that the error is reproduceble. I'm aware of using pointer in the shared memory, but I read that if attaching to the previous address then the new program should have no problem accessing the pointer, since the addresses match between the two processes; as from the output log, the addresses of the shared memory and the variables are the same, that's why I'm not sure why I can't access the pointer struct destinations *destinations.